Modern Mobile Transistor Guitar Amps How do they work?
I wonder how these modern transistor guitar amplifiers work.
Take for example the Roland Cube Street EX.



Max Power Output: 50W (2x25W)
Power Supply: AC Adaptor (DC 13V) or 8x Alkaline/NI-MH AA Battery
Current Draw: 730mA
Speakers: 2x 8 Inch Woofer + 2x2 Inch Tweeter
OperatingTime with 8x AA Alkaline battery and outputpowerswitch on Max: Approx. 4 hours
OperatingTime with 8x AA Alkaline battery and outputpowerswitch on Normal: Approx. 8 hours
OperatingTime with 8x AA Alkaline battery and outputpowerswitch on Eco: Approx. 16 hours

What are the electronic tricks to save energy?

Don't operate at anything close to max power. Keep all computing circuitry asleep as much as possible.

@MrGerber au contraire! Operate only at maximum power, that's the trick for audio amplification :) Class-D is either "the active stage is maximally on" or "maximally off", never "not close to maximum". (in essence, you PWM-pump a passive LC filter with  pairs of MOSFETs, which is what still allows the speaker to get arbitrary nice and smooth audio signals)

@MarcusMüller I didn't write "don't operate anything at close to max power", but "don't operate at anything close to max power". Driving the output in a way that keeps the power dissipation as low as possible will of course save energy. The speaker is a closed system after all

@MrGerber ah, that's true! If you operate at low volumes, of course your battery will last longer. My apologies.

@MarcusMüller No worries! My initial comment was an attempt at being humorous. OP: "How do you conserve energy in a box where the sole function is to 'get rid of' energy?" - "Burn as little energy as possible". My answer is as specific as the question

First, you can see that 13 V at 730 mA doesn’t give you anywhere near 50 W, so they’re being a bit dishonest there, probably using peak power or something like that to inflate the numbers. It’s certainly not RMS power, that would take at least 5 or 6 amps at 13 V.
How do they get efficiency? It’s most likely a Class D amplifier. These will give you much better efficiency than the old Class AB or even Class B.

I think the relationship between audio amplifier product marketeers' power ratings and reality is to be described, "loose, like estranged lovers that began to hate each other but then completely repressed the memory of the other, decades ago"
